# Not able to curl an application runs on aws ec2 via https, but http works

Tags: http, curl, amazon-ec2, https

I have an ec2 instance whose public dns (ipv4) is ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. I run a java application on the ec2 and I can fetch data via curl and http from my local laptop:

```
$ curl http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/users/1/items/2759 -verbose
*   Trying xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /users/1/items/2759 HTTP/1.1
> Host: ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> Referer: rbose
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2020 06:34:50 GMT
<
< ...expected data...
```

However, https does not work

```
curl https://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/users/1/items/2759 -verbose
*   Trying xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/local/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

My ec2 security group inbound rule:
[image]

Why can't I access my java application endpoint via https? And how can I do so?

Comment: Well, is your java server configured to serve traffic over https? (1. it is very uncommon to serve https over port 8080, 2) you can't have both http and https over the same port)

Comment: No, my java server is not. And you are right, it is very uncommon. Seems I'd better put the server behind nginx and let nginx servers the external https traffic.

Comment: yep, that's what most people do